# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/zip.so'

Tags: magento2, installation, apache2

I am trying to install Magento 2. In Readiness check , PHP Extension zip is missing. I am getting below error message -

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/zip.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It means there is an `extension=...` or `zend_extension=...` line in one of your php configuration files *(php.ini, or another close to it)* that is trying to load that extension : `ixed.5.2.lin`

Unfortunately that file or path doesn't exist or the permissions are incorrect.

1. Try to search in the `.ini` files that are loaded by PHP (`phpinfo()` can indicate which ones are) - one of them should try to load that extension.
2. Either correct the path to the file or comment out the corresponding line.

**Source :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library/5282287#5282287